# MySQL Query add limit in SubQuery

Tags: mysql, subquery

Here is my table test with values:

```
Price
----------
300
600
900
1000
1800
2000
```

I want to query such that when I search for 300 ,I should get 4 records 300,600,900,1000.

If I search for 900, I can get 600,900,1000,1800.
i.e. Two records <=900 and Two record >900

Here is the query I tried :

```
SELECT * FROM table h where CONDITIONS 
 and  (price in (select price from table where price <=900) // I want to add   LIMIT 2 in this subquery
 or price in (select price from table where price >900)//LIMIT 2
)
order by FIELD(price ,900) DESC limit 5;
```

I searched a lot on stack overflow,but nothing worked. Please help .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following...

```
select * from ((select h.* from table_name h where amount <=300 order by amount desc limit 2)
union
(select h.* from table_name h where amount >300 order by amount limit 2)) 
derived_table order by FIELD(amount,300) desc;
```

Comment: can i have more specification regarding this Question bcz i stuck in query ??

Answer (score 2):

MySQL doesn't support LIMIT in WHERE IN/EXSISTS/ANY/SOME subqueries, you can do this with UNION

```
(SELECT * /* this should be a columnlist */
 FROM tablename
 WHERE price < 900
 ORDER BY price LIMIT 2)

 UNION

(SELECT * /* this should be a columnlist */
 FROM tablename
 WHERE price >= 900
 ORDER BY price LIMIT 2)
```

The parenthesis around each select are crucial.

[See SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b15de/2)

Comment: Yes I know. Isn't there any other workaround to it except UNION ?

Comment: In this case,order by do not work.I get Error "Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY"

Comment: Just checked the MySQL documentation and there's an example exactly the same way, but maybe it's caused by SELECT *.

Comment: Can I use join ? I am not so good at JOINs  ,If you can help :)

Comment: Yes you can, but why should you. Its not less inefficient then union.  I've added a link to a fiddle in my answer, and there are no errors

Comment: Can you advice me how can I execute above query using JPQL?

Answer (score 0):

Using union because this mysql version don't accept limit in subqueries

`select * from table where price <=900 limit 2 union select * from table where price > 900 limit 2`

Comment: Please edit your answer and include some explanation in it. Code-only answers are sometimes good enough, but code+explanation answers are always better.